# Datagridview paint issue

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a datagridview in which I process the data from a datatable.  Then change the color on fields that are an issue.  I do this through the ProgressChanged event.  This is the code:

```
    private void bgwCompare_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ReportRow rr = (ReportRow)e.UserState;
        if (rr.nRow == 1 && rr.nColumn == 2)
            rr.nColumn = 2;  // If I leave this in it works, if I remove it the single cell is not colored
        if (rr.nColumn == -1)
            dgvResults.Rows[rr.nRow].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        else
            dgvResults.Rows[rr.nRow].Cells[rr.nColumn].Style.BackColor = Color.Salmon;


    }
```

This gets... REALLY bizarre...  I only appear to have a problem with a single cell out of over 1000 records.

IF I try to watch the cell get set, it works.  (see the above code rr.nRow == 1 && rr.nColumn == 2)

If I comment that code out, the cell doesn't get painted.  If I leave that code in, the cell gets painted.  I know the value getting set to itself isn't doing anything, I just used that to set a break point.  However, if I take the breakpoint off but leave the code it; it works.  I'm baffled on what the heck is going on...

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was working ok.  I restarted my computer and re-ran the project with out the "debug code" and it worked perfectly.  There must have been something in the OS that was causing issues.

Answer (score 1):

I think that if you comment your line `rr.nColumn = 2` out the code will be interpreted as like

```
if (rr.nRow == 1 && rr.nColumn == 2)
{
    if (rr.nColumn == -1)
        dgvResults.Rows[rr.nRow].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
    else
        dgvResults.Rows[rr.nRow].Cells[rr.nColumn].Style.BackColor = Color.Salmon;
}
```

and then the BackColor on [1,2] is not set as desired.

@DaBlue as you say in the comments no my code is not interpreted like this, please then try the following

```
if (false)
    MessageBox.Show("1");  // If I leave this in it works, if I remove it the single cell is not colored
if (true)
    MessageBox.Show("2");
else
    MessageBox.Show("3");
```

In this case "2" will be shown and then try out the following code

```
if (false)
    //MessageBox.Show("1");  // If I leave this in it works, if I remove it the single cell is not colored
if (true)
    MessageBox.Show("2");
else
    MessageBox.Show("3");
```

this time you won't see any pop up

IMHO you should always use curly braces even if it's an "one-liner"

Comment: That "one liner" is only for debugging and sets the variable to the same value as it is.  As I mentioned (and ironically), this line makes it work.  This line is ONLY for debugging purposes so I can set a break point where the data is having an issue in the DGV so I can see it go through the code.

Comment: And no, it wouldn't be interpreted as you have it above.

Comment: DaBlue hes right about how your code would be interpreted and also about how you should always use braces.  Especially about always using braces LOL

Comment: I've been coding c/C++/C# for 40 years.  Compile and run this and you will see it does work.  Best practice has always been 1 line is no brace, multiple uses braces.